# itoa function for byte array

Tags: c, char, byte, avr-gcc, itoa

Is there an easy way to do the following:

Convert a byte array like so `{1,3,0,2,4}` to a `char` array like so `{'1','3','0','2','4'}` or `"13024"`.

I can do the following ( I think ) but it is more cumbersome:

```
            itoa(byte_arr[0],cap_periph[0],10);
            itoa(byte_arr[1],cap_periph[1],10);
            itoa(byte_arr[2],cap_periph[2],10);
```

Something that works on avr-gcc as well.

Comment: Easy. Use a loop.

Comment: hint, `1` + `'0'` == `'1'`. You don' tneed to call any functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is to use a loop, whatever implementation you use. If you are totally sure that each element inside source array is between 0 and 9:

```
// Only works if each element of byte_arr is between 0 and 9
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    cap_periph[i] = byte_arr[i] + '0';
}
cap_periph[3]  = '\0';
```

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard function, and the second argument is not right. Also there may be issues for both cases if the elements are not between 0-9. (buffer overflows in particular in the first case).

Comment: Right, I only leave second solution, with warning, because OP's case seams to have only number between 0 and 9

Comment: That is indeed the case. Thanks!